# Why does Just My Code affect this conditional statement

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a c# Visual Studio 2017 project with a simple conditional if statement that should NOT be entered. When stepping through the code, the if statements executes. When I turn on "Just my code" in debugger options, the if statement is not entered, which is the expected behavior.  Can anyone shed light on why this is happening?

I have absolutely determined that neither condition in the if statement is true.

```
if (dataSet == null || dataSet.Tables.Count == 0)
{
    return null;
}
```

The dataset is NOT null and the table count is > 0.  With Just my code OFF, the if returns null.  With just my code ON, the if is pass over (correct behavior)

Comment: Rebuild your project, and try your debugging maneuver again.

Comment: Did you turn of Just My Code and set a breakpoint to determine which statement is triggering it? (I'm unclear if that's what you did when you determined "The dataset is NOT null and the table count is > 0")

Comment: are there any other threads accessing/setting the dataset around the same time?

Comment: Robert, rebuilt multiple times before I figured out the need for Just My Code to be "on". Greg, yes, I used quck watch on both conditions, as well as using immediate panel.  Emo, no threads.

Comment: Can you add variable "var condition = (dataSet == null || dataSet.Tables.Count == 0)" and use that variable in if? I know that in debugger and method .ToString() implemented with side effects you can got weird results, because the debugger call .ToString(). Or can you add breakpoint with action "{dataSet}, {dataSet.Tables.Count}". This will output these variables to Debug output when the breakpoint is passed. It can help you invetigate it further.